# Extending Ardent from jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation, ardent, jenssegers-mongodb

How do I get Ardent to extend from *jenssegers/laravel-mongodb* without editing the `Ardent.php` and replacing the `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` statement??
Any clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could fork the Ardent project, edit the file, then include your forked version in your composer file.

That way you retain control over the change, and it is not lost when you update or install your dependencies.

Comment: Eeeek but in that way I won't have the latest updates from the MASTER repo

Comment: @user1005319 has this question been answered? If so - can you please accept it - or provide more info

Answer (score 0):

Use [bmcmurray/ardent-mongodb](https://github.com/bmcmurray/ardent-mongodb), it's a fork of Ardent that works with [jenssegers/mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).